# Bash: date returns "invalid date" when I try to convert this date format to epoch

Tags: bash

I want to convert `17/08/2021 23:42:32` to epoch but it throws me an error

```
root@OpenWrt:~# var="17/08/2021 23:42:32"
root@OpenWrt:~# date -d "${var}" +"%s"
date: invalid date _17/08/2021 23:42:32_
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: It depends on your locale I guess. What do you get from `locale`command`?

Comment: @LMC I use openwrt and the command `locale` isn't supported. But I live in Indonesia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux supports the `%d/%m/%Y` format on some locales for output but not for input. Shown as

```
LC_ALL="es_CR" locale -c d_fmt
```

> LC_TIME
> %d/%m/%Y

Fails for input

```
LC_ALL="es_CR" date -d '17/08/2021 21:45'
```

> date: invalid date '17/08/2021 21:45'

For -d switch, US format is supported so your option is to reverse `%d/%m`

```
var=$(echo '17/08/2021 21:45' | sed -re 's@([0-9]{2,2})/([0-9]{2,2})/([^/]+)@\2/\1/\3@')
date -d "${var}" +"%s"
```

> 1629247500

Alternatively

```
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "17/08/2021 21:45"
date -d "${array[1]}/${array[0]}/${array[2]}" '+%s'
```

> 1629247500

Comment: All of this is specific to GNU `date`, which is installed e.g. on Linux out of the box, but is absolutely not standard.  On BSD (and thus also MacOS), you can specify the input date format with an `-f` option.

Comment: @tripleee -f is only for format of output, not input.

Comment: @NiKiZe Huh? No, that's the `+` format string. See the [man page.](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/date/)

Comment: @tripleee man page (on linux) has different info for -f, no format specification of input at all. but it does say "FORMAT controls the output" but got a different message as well which further lead me down the wrong path. to be clear -f is only for BSD

Comment: Yeah, that's what the comment you are responding to was explaining in the first place.